# in forms.py when i set "to_field_name" to more than one column name, it's giving me error

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, modelchoicefield

I have created a label_form_instance for modelchoicefield but the values in html are showing primary key values. To get rid of that, i use to_field_names but i can't provide more than one column name in it.

```
class firearmChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):

    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return '%s%s, %s'%(obj.make,obj.firearm_model,obj.serial_no)


self.fields['firearm'] = firearmChoiceField(queryset = firearm_db.objects.all(),to_field_name="make,firearm_model,serial_no",required=False,empty_label='Select Firearm', widget = forms.Select(attrs={'label': ' ','class': 'form-control',}))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can patch the [**`prepare_value`** [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/2.2.x/django/forms/models.py#L1235) and [**`to_python`** [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/2.2.x/django/forms/models.py#L1243) functions for that, for example:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class firearmChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):

    def prepare_value(self, value):
        if hasattr(value, '_meta'):
            return '{}:{}:{}'.format(value.make,value.firearm_model,value.serial_no)
        return super().prepare_value(value)

    def to_python(self, value):
        if value in self.empty_values:
            return None
        try:
            make, firmod, serial = value.split(':')
            return firearm_db.objects.get(
                make=make,
                firearm_model=firmod,
                serial_no=serial
            )
        except (ValueError, TypeError, firearm_db.DoesNotExist):
            raise ValidationError(self.error_messages['invalid_choice'], code='invalid_choice')
```

You thus should *not* specify the `field_name` here. In fact if we look at the original implemention, we see how this `field_name` is used:

> ```
> class ModelChoiceField(ChoiceField):
>
>     # ...
>
>     def prepare_value(self, value):
>         if hasattr(value, '_meta'):
>             if self.to_field_name:
>                 return value.serializable_value(self.to_field_name)
>             else:
>                 return value.pk
>         return super().prepare_value(value)
>
>     def to_python(self, value):
>         if value in self.empty_values:
>             return None
>         try:
>             key = self.to_field_name or 'pk'
>             value = self.queryset.get(**{key: value})
>         except (ValueError, TypeError, self.queryset.model.DoesNotExist):
>             raise ValidationError(self.error_messages['invalid_choice'], code='invalid_choice')
>         return value
> ```

In the `prepare_value`, we thus convert an object (here a `firearm_db` object) into a string that holds the value used in the `<option value="...">`s. The `to_python` function on the other hand performs the transformation back to a `firearm` object (or `None` in case the selection is empty).

You will have to ensure that the two functions are each other *inverse*: each mapping with `prepare_value` should result in the same object when we perform a `to_python` on it. If for example here the `make` contains a colon (`:`), then this will fail, so it might require some extra finetuning.

That being said, I am not sure why you want to use a more complicated value, and not use a primary key, a slug, or some hashed value for this.

Comment: I thought there might be an easy way to solve this problem. what if i combine make,firearm_model and serial_no into one column rather than using separate ones? this should solve the problem.

Comment: @addminuse: this sounds like "*data duplication*", which is typically not very good, since that means you need to keep the original columns and the "combined" column in sync, etc. which likely in the end turns out to be a harder problem.

Comment: So what  do you suggest?

Comment: @addminuse: what exactly is the problem with using a primary key? slug? or create some "hashed" identifier as a "twin" primary key?

Comment: I will try that and then i will get back to you

Comment: I use the prepare_value and to_python function. Everything works fine now but in db it is storing values as db objects. Example : firearm_db object (11)

Comment: @addminuse: well the idea is indeed that in the database a `FOREIGN KEY` is used, this will gurantee *referential integrity*, and furthermore due to indexing, etc. it will make queries faster. A form is also only a way to communicate with the *user*. You can alter model fields to communicate with the *database*, but using primary key values, is one of the ways to [*normalize* a database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyce%E2%80%93Codd_normal_form)

Comment: Understood, so how can i convert that value to human readable format. apologies for my ignorance but i am very new to django framework.

Comment: @addminuse: a human readable format *where*? In a template? In a form? In a the Django shell?

Comment: Sorry, in a template and also in a shell.

Comment: @addminuse: you can implement the `__str__` of your model (here in the `firearm_db` class), see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#str).

Comment: Thank you sir! you are a genius. Thank you very much, can you also recommend some books on django to understand it more?